# c#: Button shows a blank when cursor is enters or hovers over it

Tags: c#, button, cursor, mousehover

When cursor enters or hovers on this button (cmdRefresh) control it displays a blank square on the tooltip. Mouse events are not defined for this control and only click is event is defined

```
this.cmdRefresh.AutoEllipsis = true;
this.cmdRefresh.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ButtonFace;
this.cmdRefresh.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
resources.ApplyResources(this.cmdRefresh, "cmdRefresh");
this.cmdRefresh.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText;
this.cmdRefresh.Name = "cmdRefresh";
this.ToolTip1.SetToolTip(this.cmdRefresh, resources.GetString("cmdRefresh.ToolTip"));
this.cmdRefresh.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
this.cmdRefresh.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.cmdRefresh_Click);


public void cmdRefresh_Click()
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
        frmApplication.DefInstance.StatusBar1.Items["Message"].Text = MainModule.g_sReadyMessage;
        if (frmApplication.DefInstance.cmdRefresh.Visible)
        {
            frmApplication.DefInstance.cmdRefresh.Focus();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tried to completely delete the button and place it again? Might be some corrupted code behind.

Comment: Tried that. Does not work.

Comment: Somewhere in the code cmdRefresh.Text is getting set to "". If I make cmdRefresh.Text = null in button's parent enter event then it does not show the blank spot. But I searched in the code, nowhere cmdRefresh.Text is set to any value.

Comment: So im assuming you want nothing to show up in the tooltip? Im not at my computer at the moment but take a look at tooltip properties in the property pane.

Comment: this.ToolTip1.SetToolTip(this.cmdRefresh, resources.GetString("cmdRefresh.ToolTip"));

It is already showing text "Refresh" on the toolTip but this extra blank is appearing with tooltip text "Refresh" so there are total two texts.